# Android Studio gradle release Build taking infinite time

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proguard, androidx, build-variant

I recently updated my code base to Androidx and now trying to build production variant using the command

```
> ./gradlew assembleProduction
```

It keeps on building at the process transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease

Here is the output

```
Note: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgp: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManagerService
Note: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzs: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.SystemProperties
Note: com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.aa: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.youtube.api.locallylinked.LocallyLinkedFactory
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: io.fabric.sdk.android.FabricKitsFinder: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.internal.JRE8PlatformImplementations
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class kotlin.internal.JRE7PlatformImplementations
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$CloseGuard$Companion: can't find dynamically referenced class dalvik.system.CloseGuard
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform$Companion: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$Companion: can't find dynamically referenced class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt$Version
Note: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown field 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult$ReleasableResultGuardian mResultGuardian' in class 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown method 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService asInterface(android.os.IBinder)' in class 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown method 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement getInstance(android.content.Context,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'sun.misc.Unsafe' to keep library class 'sun.misc.Unsafe'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.xmlpull.v1.**' to keep library class 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.xmlpull.v1.**' to keep library class 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.xmlpull.v1.**' to keep library class 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.xmlpull.v1.**' to keep library class 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'android.widget.Space' to keep library class 'android.widget.Space'
Note: there were 7 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 3 references to unknown class members.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
Note: there were 6 library classes explicitly being kept.
      You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
Note: there were 49 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 1 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Ignoring unused library classes...
  Original number of library classes: 24139
  Final number of library classes:    2071
Printing kept classes, fields, and methods...
Inlining subroutines...
Shrinking...
Printing usage to [/Users/harsh/git/Mobile_Android_MVA/app/build/outputs/mapping/production/release/usage.txt]...
Removing unused program classes and class elements...
  Original number of program classes: 21242
  Final number of program classes:    21242
Optimizing (pass 1/5)...
<=<============-> 99% EXECUTING [14m 57s]
> :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProductionRelease
```

My gradle.properties looks like this

```
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> 
> org.gradle.parallel=true org.gradle.daemon=true
> # Disables R8 for Android Library modules only. android.enableR8.libraries = false
> # Disables R8 for all modules. android.enableR8 = false android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true
> 
> org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

I am using proguard and release buildType has following

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true
shrinkResources true
zipAlignEnabled true
debuggable false
```

I tried with and without androidx proguard but same result

```
-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```

Can you please help me how to solve this so I could generate a signed apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Android studio are you using? 3.4?

What happens when you compile with R8 instead of Proguard? Sometimes error messages are more explicit.

Comment: Gradle 3.4.2. I executed with R8. Works fine with it. Guess Poguard was taking some time.